# Android Facebook SDK: SSL handshake failure

Tags: android, facebook, ssl

I've got a question about the Facebook SDK on android, it seems to be an SSL issue, the response I get is:

```
{Response:  responseCode: unknown, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: -1, errorCode: -1, errorType: null, errorMessage: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x4002f768: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:741 0x5ba74d74:0x00000000)}, isFromCache:false}
```

here's my codes:

```
authButton = (LoginButton) gView.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
authButton.setFragment(this);
authButton.setUserInfoChangedCallback(mLoginBtnCallBack);
```

and here's the mLoginBtnCallBack:

```
LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback mLoginBtnCallBack = new LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
        final Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        Log.d("Sennin32", "mLoginBtnCallBack session"+session.toString());
        if(user == null){
            Log.d("Sennin32", "mLoginBtnCallBack GraphUser Null!");
            Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    Log.d("Sennin32", "mLoginBtnCallBack onSessionStateChange"+response.toString());
                    if (session == Session.getActiveSession()) {
                        if (user != null) {
                            GlFacebook.getInstance().SetFbId(user.getId());
                        } else {
                            Log.d("Sennin32", "mLoginBtnCallBack GraphUser Null again!");
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
        } else {
            GlFacebook.getInstance().SetFbId(user.getId());
        }
    }
};
```

Does anybody get the same error? Is there any solution for it?

Comment: Can you provide more information like which API call are you using, some lines of code ... ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I'v add some codes. I'm just want to get the user ID, and I'v done it before in other projects, this is my first got this problem.

Comment: Don't use SSL2 or 3. Use TLS.

Comment: Hi, is there any hint to disable SSL, and use TLS? I'v found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26483214/ but is doesn't mention how to use that instance, most info about this issue is about how to create HTTP connection with TLS, not says how to solve the Facebook issue. Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'v found what cause this error.
It's cause by the HttpResponseCache, if I disable the cache, the problem solved.

But I still want to know how to enable the cache without the error now.
I'v try to set my https connecttion by using HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory and SSLContext.
But It doesn't work, I check the Facebook lib again, found that the connection is http, but url is https, I got no idea with it now and keep to find out what happening.

Now, I just simply disable the cache and it works.